# UIImageJPEGRepresentation giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, nsdata, uiimagejpegrepresentation

In my app I am using the camera and photo library to get an UIImage,
this UIImage is then scaled down about 20 times its normal size 
I then set a NSData object based off the UIImage.

```
_regularImage = [self resizeImage:_takenImage width:100 height:100];


-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)anImage width:(int)width height:(int)height
{

    CGImageRef imageRef = [anImage CGImage];

    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;


    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;      
}

NSData *image1Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_regularImage, 1);
```

I cant seem to figure anything else out that might cause this

Thank you

LittleRy

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @jtbandes He said that it occurs on the JPEGRepresentation line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here may be that you are creating your bitmap context or UIImage in the wrong way.  Try debugging and checking if `_regularImage` is nil, or if it's invalid.  For scaling an image, I would suggest using a third party library called [ANImageBitmapRep](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANImageBitmapRep).  It's a small set of classes that allows for easy cropping, resizing, rotating, etc of images on the iPhone.  Scaling a UIImage can be done like this:

```
ANImageBitmapRep * irep = [ANImageBitmapRep imageBitmapRepWithImage:myImage];
[irep setSize:BMPointMake(myWidth, myHeight)]; // scale the image
UIImage * theImage = [irep image];
[irep release];
NSData * jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1);
```

With this sort of code I doubt that `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` would be the issue.  The `ANImageBitmapRep` class itself handles the `CGContextRef` stuff internally, making your job very much easier.

Comment: I also changed around some of my variables, so i cant say for sure if thats whats helped.  Although i will be using the Libary for many other projects, thanks